# Realm Javascript to Realm Java Version Mapping

Tags: android, react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a react native project that uses realm version 2.4.0. The project has a purely native feature implementation in Android that depends on some data stored in realm js.

After adding the Android integrations natively to the Android project, trying to invoke any methods on the realm object from Android natively throws an Illegal Argument Exception "Illegal Format of Realm file".

I assume this because the Realm dependencies in both React native and Android are mismatched.

How can I tell which versions of Realm are compatible with each other across platforms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best way to do this is look at the changelog for across all repositories you're interested in and checking the version of the realm file each version uses.